# Parsing a web page

Tags: parsing

how can I parse a web page which uses AJAX...
I will be more specific here. there is a website http://www.wordcount.org/main.php which gives the rank of a word according to it's usage.
for a given word, I want to retrieve it's rank...
how can I get it? 
this is extremely important.. thank you in a advance...

Comment: The link contains a Flash movie... :-?

Answer (score 1):

That flash page calls the following URL to get the data: http://www.wordcount.org/dbquery.php?toFind=0&method=SEARCH%5FBY%5FINDEX

If you are using PHP, then do something like:

`$url = 'http://www.wordcount.org/dbquery.php?toFind=0&method=SEARCH%5FBY%5FINDEX';`

parse_str(file_get_contents($url), $dataArray);

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/ - it simulates a browser behaviour, leaving you with a current DOM to inspect. If you're using Java, it is straightforward, for any of the .NET languages it works fine with IKVM.